# scala generics. Combining type parameters

Tags: scala

found out, that it is possible to define this syntax in scala:

```
trait X[Y, Z]
```

1. `List[Int X String]`
2. `List[X[Int, String]]`

**Questions:**

1. Are 1) and 2) equivalent?
2. What if there are three parameters in X trait?
3. Where is it specified in scala language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's duplicate as mentioned in comments.
2. Unclear question.
3. [specs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#infix-types)